# jquery sortable update database using coldfusion

Tags: jquery, sql-server, database, coldfusion, jquery-ui-sortable

There are a ton of ways to do this in PHP but I have not found any posts that do this in Coldfusion using jQuery.  If you have a link, please share that.  Otherwise, here is what I'm doing:

I have four sections (first, second, third, fourth for lack of better term) and within each section is a list of items (0-15 items in each section).  The client needs to be able to manually sort the items (I'm using jQuery sortable to do this - only within a section, not between each section).  I don't want to give the user an extra step by having a "save" button.  I'd like to store the updated order in the database when the list item is dropped.  I have the sorting part working and now I need to update my mssql database with the new order and I'm having trouble working out the loop.

Using FF firebug, this is what is being passed via post and the recordsArray[] is what I can't seem to figure out how to loop over:

`recordsArray[]=1&recordsArray[]=3&recordsArray[]=2&action=updateRecordsListings`

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: stackoverflow wont let me answer this question until another hour based on my current reputation points so for now, I'll post the link I found which does what I'm looking to do: http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd go ahead and mark this as the correct answer: 4 years later and it's still working like a champ:  http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/285

I pretty much took the solution in the blog post and renamed the variables to that of what I was using on our project. I'm not a part of that project any more so I don't have access to the source code but I can see the web page on the intranet and see the solution is still there. That is about the best I can offer for this at this time.

**Summary:** In case the link breaks, the blog post shows how to use ajax to pass a sorted list of id's ie `id_5,id_1,id_3,id_2...` to a CFC. The CFC loops through the list, extracts the id values and uses the current list position as the "sort order". The individual records are then updated, and any removed id's are deleted. See the blog entry for the full example.

```
<cftransaction>

    <cfloop list="#arguments.orderedList#" index="ndx">

        <cfset id = Val( ListLast( ndx, "_" ) )>
        <cfset position = position+1>
        <cfset updatedids = ListAppend( updatedids, id )>

        <cfquery datasource="mydsn">
            update myTable 
            set  order = <cfqueryparam value="#position#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            where id = <cfqueryparam value="#id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfquery>

    </cfloop>

    <!--- delete any items not in the list --->
    <cfquery datasource="mydsn">
        delete from myTable
        where id not in ( <cfqueryparam value="#updatedids#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )
    </cfquery>

</cftransaction>
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of code or elaborate on how you solved the issue? Link only answers are discouraged, because they are no longer useful to others when the link breaks or changes. (BTW, the link above is returning a 404 at the moment ...).

Comment: Updated the link so the 404 is resolved; going forward, I'll include code snippets that can be shared here instead of linking to a blog post. I know blogs come and go but SO is forever!  at least I hope!

Comment: Hope you do not mind, but I added a brief summary :)  If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Thank you. I'd contacted the developer who is in charge of this project now asking for a snippet (I even shared with him this SO posting). I still haven't heard back yet and your summary is great so phewy on that other guy.

Answer (score 1):

I've written two blog entries that match this to varying degrees.

This first uses datatables and drag and drop:

http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2011/5/15/Combining-JQuery-Datatable-with-drag-and-drop-functions

The second which I think is closer to what you want is a drag and drop server side app:

http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2011/6/17/JQuery-Sortable-Drag-and-Drop-lists-and-a-server-side-AJAX-save

It shows how you can drag and drop elements and use an ajax request to save the data.

Comment: I actually found both of your blog posts via google but they aren't what I'm looking for here, unless I missed something.

Comment: what I need is to figure out how to loop over the data passed to the action page (the page to process the updated list order).